# How to increase width and height of image in Flutter's carousel slider without giving the carouselSlider a height

Tags: image, flutter, carousel

I need to build a carousel slider with an image and text below the image and the image constraints need to be 250 x 250. I have the image and text inside a column but they are getting cut off saying that there was an overflow in the bottom. It works if I give the CarouselSlider widget a height but I shouldn't do that because the text varies and giving a height wont be consistent.Tried several other methods like Wrap,Expanded but none seem to work

This is how I am doing it::

```
final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',

];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       child: CarouselSlider(
          //height: 350,   //giving this a height fixes it but I shouldn't be doing it
          items: imgList.map((i) {
           return 
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                     margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                         child: Image.network(i,  height: 250, width: 250)),
                    ),
                    Text(i)
                  ],
                );

          }).toList(),
          viewportFraction: 1.0,
      )
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap Container with FittedBox and Wrap with Flexible has different effect 
you can see demo picture and use in your case

```
Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FittedBox(
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                        child: Image.network(
                          imageUrl.sponsorlogo,
                          height: 250,
                          width: 250,
                          //fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(imageUrl.toString()),
                  ],
                );
```

[image]

Wrap with Flexible

```
return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                        child: Image.network(
                          imageUrl.sponsorlogo,
                          height: 250,
                          width: 250,
                          //fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(imageUrl.toString()),
                  ],
                );
```

[image]

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
//
//     final payload = payloadFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Payload> payloadFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Payload>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Payload.fromJson(x)));

String payloadToJson(List<Payload> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Payload {
  String sponsorlogo;

  Payload({
    this.sponsorlogo,
  });

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        sponsorlogo: json["sponsorlogo"] == null ? null : json["sponsorlogo"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "sponsorlogo": sponsorlogo == null ? null : sponsorlogo,
      };
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SponsorSlider(),
    );
  }
}

class SponsorSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SponsorSliderState createState() => _SponsorSliderState();
}

class _SponsorSliderState extends State<SponsorSlider> {
  Future<List<Payload>> getSponsorSlide() async {
    //final response = await http.get("getdata.php");
    //return json.decode(response.body);
    String response =
        '[{"sponsorlogo":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80"},{"sponsorlogo":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"},{"sponsorlogo":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"}]';
    var payloadList = payloadFromJson(response);
    return payloadList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Card(
          child: new FutureBuilder<List<Payload>>(
            future: getSponsorSlide(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
              return snapshot.hasData
                  ? new SponsorList(
                      list: snapshot.data,
                    )
                  : new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SponsorList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Payload> list;
  SponsorList({this.list});

  @override
  _SponsorListState createState() => _SponsorListState();
}

class _SponsorListState extends State<SponsorList> {
  int _current = 0;

  int index = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CarouselSlider(
            //height: 200.0,
            initialPage: 0,
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _current = index;
              });
            },
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 2),
            reverse: false,
            items: widget.list.map((imageUrl) {
              return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                          child: Image.network(
                            imageUrl.sponsorlogo,
                            height: 250,
                            width: 250,
                            //fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),

                    ),
                      ),
                    Text(imageUrl.toString()),
                  ],
                );
              });
            }).toList(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do this and use this package with it for a nicer show: https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer

```
CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
                        ),
                        items: _imgList
                            .map(
                              (item) => Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    filterQuality: FilterQuality.low,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    imageUrl: item,
                                    placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                        Shimmer.fromColors(
                                      baseColor: Colors.grey[300],
                                      highlightColor: Colors.white,
                                      child: Container(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                        Text('Unknown image type !'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                      ),
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.